# How to hide spinner or loader when API call is rejected in React and Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `Redux Toolkit` in React project. I want to hide `spinner.png` image which is inside `<Error/>` component, I want to hide it when `isLoading` state changes to `false`. The isLoading State changes to false when the `API` call get rejected. I have set isLoading to false inside TopMenuSlice and redux devtools also shows that the isLoading state has been changed to false but when I check the same state inside Loading component then it shows true and because of that spinner.png image keep on showing even in rejected case. I don't know what is happening. Please help.

TOPMENU.JSX

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./topmenu.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchTopMenu } from "../../../store/features/homepage/topmenu/TopMenuSlice";
import Loading from "../../others/loading/Loading";
import Error from "../../others/error/Error";

const TopMenu = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { topmenuItems, isError, isLoading, isLoadingImage } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.topmenuReducer
  );
  console.log(isLoading);
  console.log("component rendered");

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTopMenu());
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    console.log(isLoading);
    return (
      <Loading
        topmenu="topmenu"
        isLoading={isLoading}
        isLoadingImage={isLoadingImage}
      />
    );
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <Error isError={isError} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvTopMenu">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="d-flex overflow">
            {topmenuItems &&
              topmenuItems.map((item) => {
                const { id, img, title } = item;
                return (
                  <div key={id} className="col text-center me-3">
                    <a href="">
                      <img src={img} alt={title} />
                    </a>
                    <p className="menu-title">{title}</p>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TopMenu;
```

LOADING.JSX

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./loading.css";

const Loading = ({ topmenu, isLoadingImage, isLoading }) => {
  console.log("isLoading redndred");
  console.log(isLoadingImage);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvLoading my-3 text-center">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 py-3">
              <img
                className="spinner"
                src={isLoading && isLoading === true ? isLoadingImage : ""}
                alt=""
              />
              <p className="text-capitalize">
                Please wait we are Loading
                <b className="d-block text-uppercase">{topmenu}</b>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Loading;
```

ERROR.JSX

```
import React from "react";

const Error = ({ isError }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvError my-3 text-center">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 py-3">
              <img
                className="spinner"
                src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_280b36bae7e24fdf9132a5d010c02061~mv2.png"
                alt=""
              />
              <p className="text-capitalize">
                Whoops, We apologize for the inconvenience.
                <b className="d-block text-uppercase">{isError}</b>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Error;
```

TOPMENUSLICE.JS

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { baseURL } from "../../../../api/baseUrl";

const url = "topmenu";

const initialState = {
  topmenuItems: [],
  isLoading: false,
  isError: null,
  isLoadingImage: `https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_280b36bae7e24fdf9132a5d010c02061~mv2.png`,
};

export const fetchTopMenu = createAsyncThunk(
  "topmenu/fetchTopMenu",
  async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/${url}`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log("TOPMENU NOT FOUND.......");
      throw new Error("TOPMENU NOT FOUND");
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data; // Return the data to be used as the payload in fulfilled action
  }
);

export const topMenuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "topmenu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchTopMenu.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isLoadingImage = `https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_280b36bae7e24fdf9132a5d010c02061~mv2.png`;
        state.isError = null;
        console.log("pending");
      })
      .addCase(fetchTopMenu.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.topmenuItems = payload;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isLoadingImage = ``;
        state.isError = null;
        console.log("success");
      })
      .addCase(fetchTopMenu.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isLoadingImage = ``;
        state.isError = "An error occurred while fetching data";
        console.log("rejected");
        console.log(state);
      });
  },
});

// export const { setTopmenu, setLoading, setError } = topMenuSlice.actions;
export default topMenuSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: In your Loading.jsx component, you're using the following code to display the spinner:

<img className="spinner" src={isLoading && isLoading === true ? isLoadingImage : ""} alt="" />
This logic might not be working as expected. Instead, you can directly use the isLoading prop to determine whether to display the spinner or not. You can simplify the code in your Loading.jsx component like this:

<img className="spinner" src={isLoading ? isLoadingImage : ""} alt="" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was looking into Loading Component instead of Error Component. I added a check into Error Component. Below is the edited code and is working fine now.

TOPMENUSLICE.js

```
const initialState = {
  topmenuItems: [],
  isLoading: false,
  isError: null,
//remove isLoadingImage
};

.addCase(fetchTopMenu.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        // remove isLoadingImage 
        state.isError = null;
        console.log("pending");
      })
      .addCase(fetchTopMenu.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.topmenuItems = payload;
        state.isLoading = false;
        // remove isLoadingImage 
        state.isError = null;
        console.log("success");
      })
 .addCase(fetchTopMenu.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        // remove isLoadingImage 
        state.isError = "topmenu";
        console.log("rejected");
        console.log(state);
      });
```

ERROR.JSX

```
<div className="col-12 py-3">
              {!isError && (
                <img
                  className="spinner"
                  src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_280b36bae7e24fdf9132a5d010c02061~mv2.png"
                  alt=""
                />
              )}
              <p className="text-capitalize">
                Whoops, We apologize for the inconvenience. An error occurred
                while fetching
                <b className="d-block text-uppercase">{isError}</b>
              </p>
            </div>
```

LOADING.JSX

```
const Loading = ({ topmenu }) => {
  console.log("isLoading redndred");
  // console.log(isLoadingImage);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvLoading my-3 text-center">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 py-3">
              <img
                className="spinner"
                src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_280b36bae7e24fdf9132a5d010c02061~mv2.png"
                alt=""
              />
              <p className="text-capitalize">
                Please wait we are Loading
                <b className="d-block text-uppercase">{topmenu}</b>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Loading;
```